# i got error, when i try to save object in django

Tags: python, django

Help me to solve the below issue (i am just beginner, (even I may not ask a question in the right way)).
What else I need to provide you.

> students() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stu_name'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/students`enter code here`
>   Django Version: 2.2.5
>   Exception Type: TypeError
>   Exception Value: 
>   students() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stu_name'
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\GAGAN\Desktop\tarkProject\myapp\views.py in students, line 18
>   Python Executable: C:\Users\GAGAN\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.5
>   Python Path: 
>   ['C:\Users\GAGAN\Desktop\tarkProject',
>    'C:\Users\GAGAN\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\GAGAN\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\GAGAN\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib',
>    'C:\Users\GAGAN\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv',
>    'C:\Users\GAGAN\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time: Wed, 1 Jan 2020 06:23:38 +0000'''

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import students

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render (request, 'myapp/home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render (request, 'myapp/contact.html')

def students(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        name = request.POST.get('stu_name')
        father = request.POST.get('stu_father')
        mother = request.POST.get('stu_mother')
        cl = request.POST.get('stu_class')
        s = students(stu_name=name, stu_father=father, stu_mother=mother, stu_class=cl)
        s.save()
        return render (request, 'myapp/students.html')
    else:
        return render (request, 'myapp/students.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class contact(models.Model):
    stu_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stu_father = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stu_mother = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # stuClass = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.stu_name


class students(models.Model):
    stu_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stu_father = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stu_mother = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stu_class = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __str__(self):
        return self.stu_name
```

Comment: You have a function and a model with the name `students`. You should name your model following the conventions: `Student` (singular, capital first letter)  to prevent such problems.

Comment: sir changed students to Student as you said but problem not solved

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and then migrate?

Comment: yes sir, more than it i have deleted dbsqlite and 001 002 from migration folder and done the makemigrations and migrate again. but problem of "Student() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stu_name'  "

Comment: sir problem solved. As per your suggestion i changed class name. but by mistake i also changed function name. now keeping the function name different and class name Student I got solved the problem. Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `students(stu_name=name, stu_father=father, stu_mother=mother, stu_class=cl)`
 is calling your function, rather than instantiating model. Because, your function and model name are the same.

Solution:

1. To maintain naming convention, change model name `students` to `Student`
2. Run `python manage.py makemgirations`
3. Run `python manage.py migrate`